# selecting only required lines from unix shell prompt

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

Lets say I am running
 `$: ps au`
in a shell prompt and want to select 2nd field of 5th entry in that, no matter which process it is. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With awk.

```
awk 'NR==6 { print $2 }'
```

The 6th record because you need to skip the header.

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig's answer also is equally good, accepting this because I wanted the awk approach, I'm planning to use it later on too..

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `awk` or the equivalent `perl` or `ruby` commands, you can also use more low-level tools:

```
ps au | head -6 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: oh wait, but the output is blank, I removed the cut part, it works, but I am not able to use -f option of cut... it is not recoginising the fields properly

Comment: Well, that depends on your notion of “field”. `cut` does not collapse white space like `awk` does, but considers “empty fields” something absolutely normal, and you seem to have such. Not that adding another `tr -d ' '` to the chain were difficult, but at some point, there is not really much simplicity left.

Answer (score 0):

In "ps au" output, second field is the process ID; you can extract it directly by telling to ps what you need:

```
ps a -o pid=
```

Then you just need to output the fifth line:

```
ps a -o pid= | sed '5!d'
```

Comment: I dont know what process id that might be, I just want to pick 5th record, thats it..

Comment: You don't need to know the process id that you want: 'ps a -o pid=' prints out a list of PIDs (just the same that you get with 'ps au')